# What is this line of Theano doing?

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

I don't understand if we are iterating over y as it appears what is being done with the values in y? Are they part of T.log? Are they added, multi, idk somehow combined with p_y_given_x?

```
result = -T.mean(T.log(p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y1.shape[0]), y1])
print ("result1", result.eval())


print("_________________________")
print("y ", y2)
print("y.shape[0] ", y2.shape[0])

temp =  (y2.shape[0], y2)
print("y.shape[0], y", temp)

temp2 = [T.arange(2), y2]
print("T.arange(y rows)", T.arange(2).eval())
print("[t.arange(2), y]    [[0, 1], [1, 2]]")
print("T.log(p_y_given_x) ", (T.log(p_y_given_x)).eval())
print(-T.mean(T.log(p_y_given_x)).eval())
print("#########################")


result1 1.022485096286888
_________________________
y  <TensorType(int64, matrix)>
y.shape[0]  Subtensor{int64}.0
y.shape[0], y (Subtensor{int64}.0, <TensorType(int64, matrix)>)
T.arange(y rows) [0 1]
[t.arange(2), y]    [[0, 1], [1, 2]]
T.log(p_y_given_x)  [[-1.11190143 -0.91190143 -1.31190143]
 [-1.13306876 -1.03306876 -1.13306876]]
1.10581842962
#########################
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll post this as an answer.

Quoting verbatim from [here](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html)

```
y.shape[0] is (symbolically) the number of rows in y, i.e.,
number of examples (call it n) in the minibatch
T.arange(y.shape[0]) is a symbolic vector which will contain
[0,1,2,... n-1] T.log(self.p_y_given_x) is a matrix of
Log-Probabilities (call it LP) with one row per example and
one column per class LP[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y] is a vector
v containing [LP[0,y[0]], LP[1,y[1]], LP[2,y[2]], ...,
LP[n-1,y[n-1]]] and T.mean(LP[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y]) is
the mean (across minibatch examples) of the elements in v,
i.e., the mean log-likelihood across the minibatch.
```

The values in y are the labels for the examples in a  minibatch. For example, let a minibatch of three examples have the `y`(label) vector as `[0,6,9]`(considering the handwritten digits example).
So, the `[LP[0,y[0]], LP[1,y[1]], LP[2,y[2]], ...,LP[n-1,y[n-1]]]` will be `LP[1,0], L[2,6], LP[3,9]`
Now, why are we interested in these numbers? 
That is because you need this numbers to compute the likelihood, which is defined as the average of the log probabilities for the examples in the minibatch. For example `LP[1,0]` contains the log probability that the first example belongs to class 0. You want this number to be as high as possible, since that is the truth. The mean is then taken to find the average of these numbers. And the negative sign is because the loss is negative of the likelihood. Does this help?

Comment: Posted as a code block because o/w I was getting an error.

Comment: Thanks, I did read that, that is where the original line came from. I still don't understand the interaction between y and p_y_given_x  Are we taking the log of all, finding a mean of the numbers in both vectors? One is the probability of an answer scaled between 1 and 0, (p_y_given_x) the other is the actual correct answer. How would taking the mean of a scaled and unscaled vector relate to each other?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, that all is also on the same page the line of code was taken from. I've read that page, and have the code working. I'm altering the code to try a different problem.

Comment: 1. The log is taken only for `p_y_given_x`
2. The mean is found of numbers only in`T.log(p_y_given_x)`

Comment: 3. `y` is just used to index those values of `T.log(p_y_given_x)` that we want to take mean of.  No mean is taken of the values in `y`. The values in `y` are just used as a fancy indexing mechanism.

Comment: Thank you! Almost. y is the target answer, which is binary. So am I only taking the mean of the numbers in the prediction that match 1's in the target?

Comment: No, `y` is not binary in this case. `y` contains values ranging from 0 to 9. You're taking the mean of the numbers which are log-probabilities of the correct answer. For example, in my answer above, for the third example, you want to consider on LP[3,9] for the third image in the minibatch and ignore `LP[3,0], LP[3,1],..., LP[3,8]` because that's the correct answer for that image.

Comment: There are no predictions here. Only the target, which is used to index the log-probabilities' matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118470/discussion-between-saurav-gupta-and-linda-macphee-cobb).